# Undefined reference to `TESTCLASS::TESTCLASS()'

Tags: c++, arduino

Although I read a few google-results for that error I can't find my problem for this error, not even while trying to reduce everything to its very basic content.

That's my testclass.h:

```
class TESTCLASS {
public:

  TESTCLASS();
};

int x; // I added this for testing if the file is included from my main code file
x=10; // It is and throws this error: testclass.h:8:1: error: 'x' does not name a type, which I don't understand neither, but it't not the main problem here
```

testclass.cpp:

```
#include "testclass.h"

TESTCLASS::TESTCLASS() {
  // do some stuff
}
```

and here's my main code file:

```
#include "lib/testclass.h"

TESTCLASS test;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

This throws the error

```
/var/folders/b5/qc8dstcn02v_hyvgxsq4w9vr0000gq/T//ccQOziAu.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_test':
/Volumes/Daten/stefanherzog/Documents/Nextcloud/Programmierung/Arduino/200515_growboxLibrary_test/200515_growboxLibrary_test.ino:3: undefined reference to `TESTCLASS::TESTCLASS()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
```

So even this is very basic I can't see the problem! I'm using an avr-g++ compiler within my Arduino IDE (v1.8.12).

Can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you compiling and linking testclass.cpp?

Comment: I'm including it, which works due to the error in `testclass.h`. What else could / should I do?

Comment: Include is something for inserting declarations for the **compiler**. Aside of this, each cpp file is a separate translation unit and compiled on its own. To put them altogether, the **linker** is responsible. In the command line where you specify the output binary (the executable to build), you have to provide all files (either all object files or all c++ sources if you compile and link in the same command line).

Comment: Since I never needed to do this manually I guess the Arduino IDE is doing that automatically. The command lines I got displayed always show "Compiling xyz", "linking everything together....".

Comment: if you have the testclass.cpp in folder lib, the Arduino will not compile it, because it doesn't compile files from subfolders.

Comment: @Juraj That's not completely true. Files from subdirectories are compiled when the subdirectory is named "utility".

Comment: for a sketch? 'utility' is for old Arduino library spec. but I don't see mentioned in the question that it is in a library

Comment: I tried it as a subdirectory in a sketch-folder, too. Naming it "utility" worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using subdirectories with the Arduino IDE the **subdirectory needs to be named as `utility`**. That's actually it!

Having this structure for example (in ../Arduino/libraries/):

```
./testclass
./testclass/testclass.h
./testclass/testclass.cpp
./testclass/sub
./testclass/sub/sub.h
./testclass/sub/sub.cpp
```

testclass.h:

```
#ifndef __TESTCLASS_H__
#define __TESTCLASS_H__

#include "utility/sub.h"

class TESTCLASS {
public:

  TESTCLASS();
};

#endif
```

testclass.cpp:

```
#include "testclass.h"

TESTCLASS::TESTCLASS() {
  // do some stuff
}
```

sub.h:

```
class SUBCLASS {
public:

  SUBCLASS();
};
```

sub.cpp:

```
#include "sub.h"

SUBCLASS::SUBCLASS() {
  // do some stuff
}
```

You can simply include the "main" testclass.h in your project and instantiate the class and even the subclass:

```
#include <testclass.h>

TESTCLASS test;
SUBCLASS sub;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you don't send testclass.cpp to your compiler. If so, your problem does'nt come from your code but your compiling command line.
Using gcc you should have something like :

```
g++ main.cpp lib/testclass.cpp -o testclass
```

I don't know the compilation process for arduino but i hope it will helps you finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest put testclass.cpp into the same folder as your .ino file. It should show up as a separate tab.

Put testclass.h there as well. and remove the lib subfolder.

And remove the `int x=10;` definition from the .h file. If both units are including testclass.h, that should end up in a *duplicate* error.

BTW: an assignment `x=10;` outside a function is nonsense anyway.

Comment: Alternatively (and after that works well) you can learn how and where to add your own libraries.

Comment: I don’t get what I’m doing wrong compared with existing libraries, I think I’m doing the same...

Comment: First build it as a multifile project (all in one folder). Restarting the IDE will also trigger a new internal makefile equivalent. ( Or the Sketch -- Add library menu item in the IDE)

Comment: Having all files in the same directory works properly. Moving them into the `lib` directory and restarting the IDE throws the same error... any idea?

Comment: And having the cpp's content in the .h file also works so it seems the cpp file is not included with the .h file

Comment: an `#include "something.h"` includes something.h at the position where #include ... is. Your .cpp file is obviously ignored, because there's no reason to add it to your project.